# problem with chart style when ag grid is rtl mode

Tags: charts, ag-grid

I have problem with chart style  when ag grid is rtl mode

```
enableRtl:true
```

but when chart at this mode

```
enableRtl: false
```

style of chart is very good

I try to customize style of chart but cannot solve this problem

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by overwrite  style

```
    .ag-panel.ag-dialog.ag-rtl{
    direction: ltr !important;
}
.ag-panel.ag-dialog.ag-rtl *{
    direction: ltr !important;
}
```